# 1.a."I have not painted a room to date" 1.b."I have not painted a room till now"

Tags: present-perfect, american-english, british-english, present-tense

1.a."I have not painted a room to date"
1.b."I have not painted a room till now"

2.a "To date I have not painted a room"
2.b "Till now I have not painted a room"

Could you pls tell me, Do these sentences mean "i have not yet painted a room" or "I have just painted a room?

Comment: They don't say whether you have actually painted the room, or are about to paint it. They say you have never done so before.

Comment: @Weather Vane then how about " I have not recieved an email till now" and till now i have not received an email"

Comment: These are someone else's actions, not your own. It's a different situation, and obviously you have received an email.

Comment: @Weather Vane "To date i have not received an email" and "I have not received an email to date". Does first sentence mean i have not received an email and second means i have received an email or they both mean i have received an email?

Comment: They both mean that you have not received any email.

Comment: None of these sentences seem very idiomatic. You might say something like "I have never painted a room before."

Comment: @Weather Vane So what i understoof that with till now "i have received" an email but with "to date" i have not received" an email

Comment: Please don't conflate two different situations. The question is about painting a room yourself. But with the email example, "until now" implies that you have received an email, and "to date" means before now, you still have not had an email.

Comment: Back to the question, there is no *implication* about whether you just painted the room, or will paint it now. It only says you never painted before.

Comment: @Weather Vane Much apprecicated.This time I am clear  :)

Comment: "To date" is not something that people say much, outside of committees and people who want to sound important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentence groups 1 and 2 are identical, so I'll only talk about group 1

1a means, "I have never in my life painted a room". 1b means, "I haven't painted a room before" and strongly implies that this situation is about to be over, meaning I'm painting a room right now, or I'm just about to paint a room.

If your question is actually about receiving an email as your comments suggest, and not about painting rooms at all, then 1a means, "I have not received a particular email", while 1b is nonsense because it means both (1) I have not received it and (2) the situation of not having received it is now over, meaning I have received it.

Comment: Don't you think the OP should be edited and their comments added *within* the text itself?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that would be better, and maybe I should have done that instead of answering right away, but I've attempted that kind of communication in comments with this user before for the same reason of not asking what they really want to know in the question, but just got a series of inconclusive answers back. So this time I took a shortcut.

Comment: So, if a user hadn't understood where the problem lied because "Until/til now I have not painted a room [until now]" makes full sense to me, they should have looked at the comments?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm having trouble parsing your sentence. Who is "a user" and who is "me"?

Comment: Sorry. I'll try again: If a user, i.e someone who uses ELL, had not understood what the problem was with the examples they (just like me = Mari-lou), should have read the comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, whatever Bilal wanted answered, it seems I hit it. And whatever some other ELL user comes to this question for, hopefully they'll find help in my answer too. It's not ideal, but I've herded enough cats for one day

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you have not painted a room before.

I would use **until** instead of **till**, but in those examples, the possibility exists that you just painted your first room. What's more likely is that you're just about to start painting your first room.